# How to replicate the last value of an attribute in all records with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have this collection and I need to replicate the value of last hour **earnings** in all records with the same url

```
[
  {
    earnings: 10,
    hour: "15:00",
    impressions: 165,
    pageViews: 12,
    clicks: 5,
    url: "energiamundial.com.br",
    date: "2021-01-11"
  },
  {
    earnings: 20,
    hour: "16:00",
    impressions: 200,
    pageViews: 210,
    clicks: 65,
    url: "energiamundial.com.br",
    date: "2021-01-11"
  }
]
```

**expected result after querie:**

```
[
  {
    earnings: 20,
    hour: "15:00",
    impressions: 165,
    pageViews: 12,
    clicks: 5,
    url: "energiamundial.com.br",
    date: "2021-01-11"
  },
  {
    earnings: 20,
    hour: "16:00",
    impressions: 200,
    pageViews: 210,
    clicks: 65,
    url: "energiamundial.com.br",
    date: "2021-01-11"
  }
]
```

how to make this querie with mongoose?